# Grind coffee with a blade grinder for a moka pot?

Tags: coffee

I'm thinking about buying a moka pot.

I have a blade grinder.

Will a blade grinder grind coffee beans fine enough for a moka pot?

I can't really afford an expensive grinder and I don't want to use pre-ground coffee, because I heard it loses quality quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as it's a decent quality blade grinder.  It's how I fill my moka pot, which I've been using 5 days a week for the last 4 years.

You can't do actual espresso in a blade grinder (it's not possible to get the grind consistent and fine enough).  But moka pots are a lot more flexible in the grind of coffee that they will accept.  Just grind it almost as fine as you can -- this takes about 30-40 seconds of grinding in mine -- and put it in the basket.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a (decent quality) blade grinder can do an acceptable job at a fine grind.

Blade grinders don't do well at coarse grinds: if you try you generally get a very uneven grind.  But for find grind, you run it longer and generally get a sufficiently even grind.  You don't have the same degree of control over the grind as with a burr grinder, however.  You have to experiment with how long to run your grinder for a given quantity of beans.  You also have to be careful not to run it too long and overheat the beans.

I like to drip coffee and use a blade grinder because it was cheap and I don't mind if the taste is somewhat more bitter than it would be with a coarser grind.  I use about an ounce of beans and grind it for 12-15 seconds.